# How do we reuse the nodekeystore.jks generated by X509Utilities in Corda network?

Tags: blockchain, keystore, corda

In our corda project we are running the nodes in devmode. Every time we do some changes in the flow implementation we re-deploy the nodes with the help of `./gradlew clean deployNodes` command in our dev environment.

So as part of the requirements we need to have a constant public key for a set of flows to work. but every time we redeploy with the above command a new set of `truststore.jks nodekeystore.jks sslkeystore.jks` is generated for each node .

How can we reuse these self signed certificates generated by X509Utilities so that we can utilize the same `nodekeystore.jks` which would result in the same public key in every build of the nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `./gradlew deployNodes` which rebuilds everything, you can simply rebuild a certain module using `./gradlew :module-name:build`.